# Website not rendering correctly in IE, but ok in Firefox an Chrome

Tags: internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox, rendering

Hoping someone may be able to help

We have a newly created website www.bosworthsgc.co.uk using a premium theme.

When I view the website in Chrome and Firefox the site looks fine

However when looking at this in various versions of Internet Explorer it seems to be "stretching" the pages or images.

If anyone can offer any advice it would be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any error from my side. Just the newsletter form is a big dizzy. Else is ok. You might want to reduce the number of scripts that the page calls. There are a lots of unused js files and css files that you don't need. Please share any screenshot if possible.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  In particular if you look at the foot of the home page the images of the blog posts are distorted whereas on Chrome or Firefox they are the correct size.  Not sure how to add a screen shot here. The css files - would this be within the theme itself?